# Extract & categorize data from strings of varying formats using Python

Tags: python, regex

The data I'm working with are strings containing city, state and zip codes that, unfortunately, are not all formatted the same. My goal is to end up with three strings: city, st, zip.

While most lines (40K+ records) have a comma separating the city from the state, some do not. Worse, some lines have a comma, but no space between city and zip (which may contain 5 or 9 digits). And some cities have more than one word. Here is a sample covering all three situations:

```
samples = ["Green River Washington 98100-1111", "Spokane, WA 98222", "Riverton,UTAH 84065"]
```

One consistency I've found is that the zip code is always last and there always appears to be a space before it. Using this and `re.findall`, I believe I am satisfactorily extracting the zip code (I'm currently leaving the original string in tact). However, I'm having trouble getting my head around how to handle the city and state.

My test code:

```
for str in samples:
if ',' in str:
    print str.split(',')[-1]
else:
    it = re.finditer(r'\b[ ,][\w]*', str)
    for match in it:
        print "'{g}' was found between the indices {s}".format(g=match.group(), s=match.span())
```

If a comma does exist, I'm trying to take advantage of that. If the comma doesn't exist, I'm trying to use `re.finditer` to identify the locations of the breaks. While I believe I can ultimately make this approach work, it isn't very clean nor does it handle extra spaces well.

Is there a better way to handle this task?

Comment: is your state ALWAYS present and in 2 letter abbreviation form?

Comment: using `str.split()` with no arguments splits on whitespace, and handles multiple spaces just fine.

Comment: @Anzel: Sometimes the state is spelled out but I believe it is always present. Good point that I need to double check that though.

Comment: @Wilduck: Thanks for that piece of information.

Comment: This is not going to be easy, unless you have a list of all valid states and their abbreviations. How else would the regex know where to split `"New York New York 12345"`?

Comment: @iLikeStrongJava, if states is an option, there are only 50 states abbrev., put it in a list and extract it first from your dataset, the remaining right will be zipcode and left will be city (if exists)

Comment: Your data is too unstructured for a programmatic approach to work 100%.  Even with a table of states how will you handle Ohio City, Ohio or any similar situation.  Washington, DC?  If you only have to do this once you can get through most of it by using text to columns in Excel and narrowing down by the strings that have commas first.  Then do it by spaces and see which ones have more or less than 3 columns, etc.

Comment: One other factor working in my favor is that nearly all the entries are from the same state, and only a handful of states overall. I'll have to check if any are states with two word names. Yes, I only have to do this once so bringing the results into a spreadsheet for validation is an option. Unless others have ideas, I think I'll try to partition the zip code off and then grab the first word on the right of the remainder as the state. I haven't looked for a method to partition from the end of a string; does that exists?